# Nested deserialisation fails with "This field is required"

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to serialize a nested User with its Profile.
GET requests work well, but POST return the following error:
b'{"profile":["This field is required."]}'

But 'profile' is send with my request:

```
         {
            'username': 'username1',
            'password': '123456!',
            'first_name': 'name1',
            'last_name': '2',
            'email': 'test@mail.de',
            'profile': {
                'role': 3,
                'description': 'test'
            }
        }
```

My Serializers:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    role = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=Profile.ROLE_CHOICES, required=True)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['description', 'role']


class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    date_joined = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=100)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=100)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=100)
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=100)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=100)
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'date_joined', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'profile']
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print('todo')
        return user
```

My post method:

```
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.data)
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
          .....
```

which returns:

```
<QueryDict: {'username': ['username1'], 'password': ['123456!'], 'first_name': ['name1'], 'last_name': ['2'], 'email': ['test@mail.ru'], 'is_active': ['True'], 'profile': ['role', 'description']}>
Bad Request: /api/user/
b'{"profile":["This field is required."]}'
```

Do you have any tips to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the request was send as multipart/form.
The deserialization only works if it is send as "application/json"

To fix it I changed my testcase to use the APIClient provided by DRF:

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

client = APIClient()
```

In my settings.py I added the following to the configuration:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json'
}
```

Here is further information about setting up the tests: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#setting-the-default-format

Comment: Hi, have you another way for this case?